# Component bodies physically touching

Tags: components, electromagnetism, pcb-assembly

Is it ok when components touch each other (with body, not leads) after assembly? I know that resistors should be ok, but how about capacitors? Is it ok when I assemble them densely? Will there be any magnetic or electric interference (inductance?) if they are too close? How about other components?

Comment: I've seen sloppy assembly scratch the lacquer off of through hole resistors so they are shorted.

Comment: Another point that has not been mentioned is insulation withstand.  Air is generally a good insulator and if you have two components with compromised insulation they are safer if not touching.  Matters more as the voltage goes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radial can caps often have very thin insulation and the can is connected to the negative lead. It is fine to touch them if the negative lead is connected on the pcb. Assembly isn't too much fun if there's a lot of components in a tight space, and repair/trouble shooting will be needlessly difficult.

If you fit large ones they should be restrained somehow, which is hard if they are packed together for space reasons.

As for resistors, not withstanding the other comments, if your design is that tight I would seriously consider moving to smd parts. There is almost no good reasons not to.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule it's sort of OK, although it's a really bad idea if one of them is a power resistor or other component which will get hot.

However, it's a very bad idea to lay out a design assuming spacing that tight. The problem is that sooner or later you'll get caught by a bunch of components that are a bit big, and then you won't be able to fit them in the space available.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's a not a final design, but a prototype I'm building and after some changes, space got tight and components got really close to each other/touching.

Comment: From an electrical point of view it might be okay, but if your board goes through some thermal cycles, you could end up with parts popping off the board, cracked capacitors, ...